# Why can't I retrieve a Developer Certificate In VisualStudio 2015 Community on Windows 2012 R2? RPC unavailable, script fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-server-2012-r2, vs-community-edition

I start Visual Studio 2015 Community running as an administrator.

I open my UWA / Win8.1 XAML project and it warns me with the following:

[image: get dev cert]

I click [I Agree] and continue.

The following appears:
[image: script crash]

I thought maybe that was related to IE security -- since it is doing some kind of odd JScript thing there.  I opened up all security settings in IE. Wide open and still nothing.

I can confirm that I do have good connectivity to the Internet.

I click [Yes] and I see:
RPC Server unavailable.

[image: com surrogate]

I click [Retry] and I see:

[image: RPC server gone]

Remote Procedure call failed!

Finally, i see the following.

[image: com surrogate is dead]

COM Surrogate has stopped working.
That's it.  It's dead, Jim.

Does anyone know why this occurs and/or a workaround to this?
Is it just not possible?

**Desktop something or another.**

Also, before I could even get this far I was warned that I had to install some Desktop expansion something or other and I did that to get this far.

**Edit**

**Note**: Opening Firewall didn't help.  Was able to capture the path to that jscript :
https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.26709.00/DefaultLogin_PCore.js
It has been minified though so it's unhelpful for the most part.

Comment: Just thought about this and now I'm looking to add an exception on the Firewall to allow the devenv.exe through.  Maybe that will fix it?

Comment: Try restarting the Remote Procedure Call (RPC) windows service.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I tried it and still no success.  Are you only allowed to have one license on limited number of machines? I am able to debug / run on two other machines (2 win10 machines).